# Intersection between two 3D planar rectangles

Tags: postgis, intersection, 3d, sfcgal

I am doing research in roof reconstruction from different data sources.

After previous steps I receive a (plane) 3D rectangle by roof-part, stored with a 2D polygon, a 3D centroid point and a normal vector (to the plane) in PostgreSQL.
As the next step I'd like to cut the (overlapping) planes and calculate the intersection lines (e.g. ridge lines) so they fit together. It would be possible to calculate a 3D polygon / 3D surface from the stored roof-part data.

How should I calculate this? ST_3DIntersection from PostGIS seems propably not to be the right way... Maybe the Intersection3D function from SFCGAL? Unfortunately I've never used this lib.

Comment: Would you be able to add a drawing of the situation? ST_3DIntersection already *is* SFCGAL, why do you think it is not the right way?